# How to install project in git repository correctly in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip, installation

Im newbie in python and know i a task from my lecturer to use ANFIS. so I intall anfis in my virtual environent using

```
pip install anfis
```

and now I try to import that

```
import anfis
import membership #import membershipfunction, mfDerivs
import numpy
```

i got problem

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'membership'

so what I must do?

Comment: so i try pip install membership and ERROR: No matching distribution found for membership

Comment: i try to look inside the folder library and there is a folder named membership, so how can I inport that module?

Comment: which library is membership in?

Comment: in anfis library, that library folder contain membership folder

Comment: and inside that folder there are membershipfunction.py and mfderivs.py

Comment: okay then try `from anfis import membership`

Comment: still error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'membership'

Comment: probably it is not considered as a module. What happens if you do `import anfis` then type `anfis.membership` or what is the result of `"membership" in dir(anfis)`?

Comment: still same, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'membership'

Comment: import anfis
"membership" in dir(anfis)

is it right code to run?

Comment: No just `"membership" in dir(anfis)`

Comment: error : name 'anfis' is not defined

Comment: You first have to import anfis before you run the code

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'membership

Comment: No just run only two lines of code. The `import anfis; "membership" in dir(anfis)` do not run the line import membership. Or rather comment cout that line

Comment: if ; is new line, still same ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'membership"

Comment: Are you running a script? Or are you using the shell? There is no way you should get an error. You should only get either True or False. But it seem you are doing something else.

Comment: i try run it in spyder

Comment: spyder has an interactive shell- the iPYTHON SHELL. In the shell, run the two lines of code I gave you. Do not try to import the membership. If this does not work, then it means that the line `import anfis` itself does not work. meaning your `anfis` module is broken. You will have to reinstall it

Comment: still same error

Comment: Then it seems you cannot even import `anfis` meaning the issue is with `anfis` and not `membership`. You should install `anfis` again eg `pip install anfis --force`

Comment: I already try it but it's not working, but after I trial and error, this cannot be imported because python version, but I really appreciate you helping me sir

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `membership` is part of the `anfis` package, but you are trying to import it as if it were an independent package in itself. Since you haven't installed any package called membership (probably because it doesn't exist as a package), you are getting a ModuleError.

**Solution**:

First of all, **remove the following statement from your code**, which is causing the error message:

```
import membership
```

Next, since you are already importing the entire `anfis` package, you can just use a function from the `membership` module in your code like this:

```
import anfis

# some code

mfc = membership.membershipfunction.MemFuncs(mf)
```

Check this [link](https://github.com/twmeggs/anfis/blob/master/anfis/tests.py) from the anfis GitHub repo  for an example on how to use the membership function.

Comment: please, often take time to read the comments above before posting

Comment: still same problem, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'membership"

Comment: i try yout link anfis github, copy and run it, still no module named membership

Comment: Did you remove the "import membership" statement?

Comment: its because python version that I cant imported that, thank you for helping me

Comment: @Onyambu Sorry, I just wanted to contribute, but I couldn't comment since I'm still new here. But you're right, seems like there was a lot of extra info in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common problem. Try reading through this discussion and see if anything there helps you.

https://github.com/twmeggs/anfis/issues/4

Comment: Btw, @Rhavif Budiman, did you try using:
```import anfis; import membership.mfDerivs; 
import membership.membershipfunction; 
import numpy```

Comment: it does not work, but after I search in the link that u send to me, and some trial and error, it cants imported because a different version of python, but thank for helping me

Comment: @RhavifBudiman Oh ok, I guess you're on Python 3? Sorry for not being able to provide a better resource.